# Space on the right of the page

Tags: html, css

In my portfolio website for width less than 576px, there is a space that occurs on the right side of the page out of nowhere. It is not padding, margin, or anything else.

[image]

Please help me out.
here is the link of the website: https://dhairyadutt.github.io/Portfolio/
**inspect (576px->575px)**

Comment: Hey Dhariya, please update your question with the code so that people can debug your code and find you a solution. Currently, it is not possible to look into your problem just with your image.

Comment: sorry, did not notice. is it okay that I've sent the repo link? or its dangerous for me?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: sure, I am new here. did not know about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of `@media (max-width: 768px) .container {padding: 3rem 0;}` and check.

Answer (score 1):

you should try to add

```
*{
margin : 0px;
}
```

to the CSS.
This should remove the base margin to the root of the webpage

**Edit:** Could not reproduce error

Answer (score 0):

It occurs due to content overflow the container,
Try doing this:

```
body{overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: then the website won't scroll, also it did not work out. thanks though. Also the content is not overflowing